# Chart js - Line chart cuts border for lines in boundaries

Tags: chart.js, chart.js2

I've surprised about how chart js line chart cuts border for lines in boundaries.
I expect same border in [January, February] as [February, March].
I know that chart js provide some callbacks for ticks and scales (afterBuildTicks for instance), then I could subscribe on this events and modify chart ticks array. But I think it's overhead.
Any ideas how get it easier?

JSFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/yoax05yx/

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('myChart');
enter code here var data = {
labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
datasets: [
    {
        data: [0, 0, 20, 0, 0, 100, 100],
        fill: false,
    }
]};
var myBarChart = Chart.Line(canvas,{
data:data, options:{}});
```

Same, only data : https://jsfiddle.net/muz639kL/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chart.js does a pretty good job of auto-sizing scales and figuring out the best configuration for tick step sizes and spacing, however it is not always perfect.  In your example, since you have data points that sit directly on the x axis and the top gridline, the lines appear to get chopped off.

When this occurs, you have to step in a be more explicit with your scale definition.  In this case, you could set the tick `min` and `max` so that the scale extends past your datapoints, thus preventing the line clipping.

Here is an example.

```
var myBarChart = Chart.Line(canvas, {
  data: data,
  options: {
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          min: -20,
          max: 140
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

I forked your jsfiddle showing what this looks like in your specific example.  Here is the [updated version](https://jsfiddle.net/jordanwillis/m7nztrx2/).

Comment: Can I dynamically setup min and max for a chart by getting the chart step size?

Comment: @EugeneZakharov You can actually dynamically set the min and max just by implementing your own function that would return min and max from your dataset + some buffer.  You can also use a combination of stepSize and fixedStepSize to help chart.js figure out the min and max better automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I used workaround to prevent line from being cutted:

```
      ticks: {
        callback(tick) {
          if (!Number.isInteger(tick)) {
            return ''
          }

          return tick
        },
        min: -0.9,
        max: 100.9,
      },
```